# How to register coordinates and draw a line?

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent, pyqtgraph

Using pyqt I set up a ViewBox widget, and inside that widget I need to register two clicks of my mouse to draw a line using pyqtgraph roi that connects the clicks.

This is my base code with comments what I would like it to do:

```
def onClick(ev):
    #First mouse click - ONLY register coordinates
    #Second mouse click - register coordinates of second click
    #Draw line connecting the two clicks
w.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(onClick)
```

This code works to return a mouseclick and draw a line, BUT I don't know how to make it wait for the second mouseclick:

```
def onClick(ev):  
    x = ev.pos().x()
    y = ev.pos().y()
    print(x,y)
    line = pg.LineSegmentROI([[711,265], [295, 170]], pen=(4,9)) 
    vb.addItem(line)
w.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(onClick)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly untested code, but should get you where you want to go. Basically, you have a global array, which contains either one or two sets of coordinates. If the array is empty when the handler is called, that mean you're dealing with the first click, and you store those coordinates. If the array already contain one set of coordinates, you're dealing with the second click and you can draw your line, but don't forget to empty the array so it can work again if you click a third time

```
clicks = []
def onClick(ev):
    global clicks
    x = ev.pos().x()
    y = ev.pos().y()
    if len(clicks)==0:  # First mouse click - ONLY register coordinates
        print("First click!")
        clicks.append((x,y))
    elif len(clicks)==1:  # Second mouse click - register coordinates of second click
        print("Second click...")
        clicks.append((x,y))

        # Draw line connecting the two clicks
        print("...drawing line")
        line = pg.LineSegmentROI(clicks, pen=(4,9)) 
        vb.addItem(line)

        # reset clicks array
        clicks[:] = [] # this resets the *content* of clicks without changing the object itself
    else:  # something went wrong, just reset clicks
        clicks[:] = []
```